# python3 - apply a regex map to column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, replace

How to apply a regex to a data frame column?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['negative', 'positive', 'neutral', 'neutral', 'positive']})
cdict = {'n.*': -1, 'p.*': 0}
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(cdict)

print(df.head())
```

Current output is:

```
:        col1  col2
: 0  negative   NaN
: 1  positive   NaN
: 2   neutral   NaN
: 3   neutral   NaN
: 4  positive   NaN
```

But expected results:

```
:        col1  col2
: 0  negative   -1
: 1  positive   1
: 2   neutral   -1
: 3   neutral   -1
: 4  positive   1
```

Comment: Note that your dict should be `cdict = {'n.*': -1, 'p.*': 1}` for your expected output, I assume its a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `series.map` use `series.replace` with `regex=True`

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].replace(cdict,regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, you don't need to have a `dict` for this at all. You can save on some space there.

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`Series.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
In [1927]: import numpy as np

In [1928]: conds = [df.col1.str.startswith('n'), df.col1.str.startswith('p')]

In [1929]: choices = [-1, 0]

In [1930]: df['col2'] = np.select(conds, choices)

In [1931]: df
Out[1931]: 
       col1  col2
0  negative    -1
1  positive     0
2   neutral    -1
3   neutral    -1
4  positive     0
```